# Running parallel jobs on multicore using GNU parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu, multicore

I need to run multiple jobs on a multicore (and multithreaded) machine. I am using the [GNU Parallel utility](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) to distribute jobs across the cores to speed up the task.
The commands to be executed are available in a file called 'commands'. I use the following command to run the GNU Parallel.

cat commands | parallel -j +0

As per the guidance at this location- [gnu parallel](http://www.admin-magazine.com/HPC/Articles/GNU-Parallel-Multicore-at-the-Command-Line-with-GNU-Parallel), this command is supposed to use all the cores to run this task. My machine has 2 cores and 2 threads per core. The system monitor however shows 4 CPUs (CPU1 and CPU2 belong to core1, CPU3 and CPU4 belong to core2). 
Each job (simulation) takes about 20 seconds to run on a single core. I ran 2 jobs in parallel using this GNU parallel utility with the command above. I observe in the system monitor that, if the 2 jobs are assigned to cpu1 and cpu2 (that is the same core), there is obviously no speed-up. They take about 40seconds to finish, which is about the time they would take if run sequentially. However, sometimes the tool distributes the 2 jobs to CPU1 and CPU3 or CPU4 (which means, 2 jobs are assigned to 2 different cores). In this case, both jobs finish parallely in 20 seconds.

Now, I want to know if there is a way in which I can force the tool to run on different "cores" and not on different "threads" on the same core. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: What OS are you running? How do you determine which core the jobs are being run on?

Comment: I am running ubuntu on an intel i3 (dual core) machine. It has 2 threads per core (I find this info by using the command lscpu). I use the gnome system monitor to see which cores the jobs are being run on.

Answer (score 1):

GNU Parallel spawns processes. It does not decide which core to run it on. Your OS does that. GNU/Linux makes it possible to save power by having processes spawn on cores the same physical CPU to save power:

```
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/sched_mc_power_savings
```

(See https://lesswatts.org/tips/cpu.php)

If you computer is set up for saving power this may be the case for you.

GNU/Linux also makes it possible to control which cores a process should be spawned on. Using `taskset` you can tell GNU/Linux to spawn on every other core using the mask 10101010(bin)=0xAA; here shown for a 128 core machine:

```
cat commands | taskset 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa parallel -j +0
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this. Initially I thought that if I disable every other core, I will be forcing the jobs to run on 2 different virtual cores (given a 2 core, 2 threads/core machine). However, I realise that, if I disable every other logical core using the taskset, the total execution time increases tremendously. So, I guess I will let them run as is. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I am completely ignorant here can you elaborate?  I have a program that runs in 20s on a 4 core server (see details below). I accomplish by setting -j1.  What should I expect?  In a pure concurrency situation, I run -j4 in the same time as -j1 with 4 cores (20s)? What I see experimentally is -j1 it takes (20s for 1), -j2 (23s for 2), with -j3 (27s for 3), with -j4 33.5s (for 4)  AKA "concurrency penalty" is about 15% as I step up the concurrency
Architecture:x86_64;CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit;CPU(s):4; Thread(s) per core:2;Core(s) per socket:2;Socket(s):1;NUMA node(s):1;Stepping:4

Comment: @AaronSoellinger Ask a new question. Include an MCVE.